# Could SpeechClient.dll rebuild with .NET Framework 4.0 and support Windows 7?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

The SpeechClient.dll, which is part of the Congnitive Service, could it be rebuild with .NET Framework 4.0 and support Windows 7?
It currently only surrpot .NET 4.5 and Windows 8+.
Please MSFT help to answer the question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your inquiry. We are not planning to rebuild with .NET Framework 4.0 with support on Windows 7.